# How do I remove my SkyDrive information from Office?

Tags: microsoft-office-2010, windows-live, onedrive

I store my OneNote notebooks on SkyDrive.  On my work computers, Office 2010 retains my SkyDrive info (I installed the sign in assistant as suggested;  I don't know what effect this has).

I'm now changing jobs and would like to wipe all information related to my SkyDrive account from my work computers.   The sign-in assistant doesn't seem to have an uninstaller, and OneNote seems to be retaining my login info for SkyDrive.  How can I remove all traces of my SkyDrive account from Office?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since time was short, I solved this by creating a throwaway Hotmail account and logging into Windows Live with it on my work machines.  I'm sure there's a better way, but this seemed to do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Try uninstalling the Browser Helper object under Internet Explorer.

Comment: I disabled the BHO, but there's no change in OneNote.

Answer (score 1):

Th easiest way to do this is to open the Credentials Manager in Windows and delete the SkyDrive account login details there.  This [article](http://www.trishtech.com/win7/remove_credentials_from_credential_manager_in_windows_7.php) gives you step by step instructions on how to do this on a Windows 7 machine.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to remove Skydrive from your computer, then log out of Skydrive on the web. The web locations will still appear, however nothing can be selected/opened.

Answer (score 0):

The true way to do this is pretty simple and just worked for me with OneNote 2010. Navigate to File -> Share -> 3. Web Location. Where your Live user is shown as logged-in, click "Not (username)". This logs out your account and pops-up the Windows Live login modal. Click 'Cancel' and you should be set.

Answer (score 0):

Following solution worked for me.

1) Goto -> Control Panel -> User Accounts -> Mange your credentials, Clear the cached account for Skydrive.
2) Next time when you open OneNote , it will prompt for your credentials.